# Communication between ViewModel and UserControl's view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I working on WPF MVVM project. I'm struggling with communication between viewmodel of my `MainWindow` and view of `usercontrol`, placed inside `MainWindow`.

So I have:

- UserControl
- MainWindow
- MainWindowViewModel

My **UserControl** is very simple:

```
<Grid MouseDown="UIElement_OnMouseDown">
    <Rectangle Fill="BlueViolet" />
</Grid>
```

with code-behind (just rise an event when rectangle is clicked, and pass coordinates):

```
public partial class FooUserControl : UserControl
{
    public FooUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler<BarEventArgs> BarClick;
    private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        double x = e.GetPosition(this).X;
        double y = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
        string value_to_pass = "[" + x + "," + y + "]";

        BarEventArgs bar = new BarEventArgs() { Bar = 2, Foo = value_to_pass };
        BarClick?.Invoke(sender, bar);
    }
}
```

My **MainWindow** doesn't have code-behind. Just xaml. As you can see I pass click event via Command to **MainWindowViewModel**:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <local:FooUserControl>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="BarClick">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </local:FooUserControl>
</Grid>
```

and finally my **MainWindowViewModel** has just this command:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ICommand ClickedCommand => new RelayCommand<BarEventArgs>(o => Clicked(o.Foo));
    private void Clicked(string a)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Clicked " + a);
    }
}
```

So, communication from UserControl's view to MainWindow's viewmodel, via command, works great. But, **how can I communicate in opposite way? From MainWindowViewModel to UserControl's view?**

Comment: What kind of communication you wan to do...? You can look for two way binding.

Comment: Expose an ICommand on the surface of your UserControl.  Bind to it in your ViewModel.  Now the UserControl can communicate directly to your view model.  Shazam.  Communication back?  Expose a property on the UserControl for whatever it needs.  Perhaps a Point?  Or maybe a Shoe?  I dunno.  Now, the view model sets their property to the shoe of the required color, and by change notification the UserControl can update itself.  You have MVVM-approved two-way communications.  Blam.

Comment: Is your `FooUserControl` supposed to be reusable across applications (=UserControl) or specific to your application (=View). UserControls don't have a ViewModel (just provide dependency properties to bind to one), only Views have specific viewmodels (`UserView` => `UserViewModel`).

Comment: @Tseng This is what I have. When I said about "ViewModel" I mean viewmodel of the view where FooUserControl was placed.

Comment: That's what the `INotifiyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` interfaces are for, to tell the view when a value has changed, which you obviously should know since you implement an `ObservableObject` which sounds like a type that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (INPC)

Comment: @Tseng thanks. I understand better now. In the View I can watch certain properties from ViewModel and if they change, do some animation in the View. I just need a moment to analyse Mediator Design Pattern and MVVM Lights's Messenger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ViewModels should not access your Views directly. They should not care about Views at all. All they do, is, provide properties to make data available. Views can now bind to these properties.

So, all communication from the ViewModel to the View works through Bindings only. When the ViewModel has to tell the View something, it provides a property. Then it's up to the View to bind to that property and do something with it - whatever this might be.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but like I said in other comments, my usercontrol doesn't have viewmodel. Should I create a viewmodel for my UserControl?

Comment: You have two possibilities. First: create a ViewModel for your UserControl as you suggested. Second: Set the `DataContext` of your UserControl to your `MainWindowViewModel` so that your UserControl can access properties of your `MainWindowViewModel`.

Comment: In first case, should I use Messenger from mvvm light to communicate usercontrol viewmodel with mainwindow viewmodel or is there other way to go?

Comment: The messenger from mvvm light would be a good approach, because you can keep your ViewModels loosely coupled. (They don't need to know each other.)

Answer (score 2):

MVVM says,view should talk only to its viewmodel and viewmodels can talk to other viewmodels only(and model).
What you need is a Mediator.
[image]
 Source : http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger/
With this you don't have to create event in your usercontrol.you can communicate to any viewmodel that is instantiated.
You can use mvvm-light,which provides an implementation of Mediator pattern(Messenger).it also provides other tools that will help you build MVVM application.
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696340/Thinking-in-MVVMLight-Messenger) is a tutorial to MVVMLight Messenger.

With binding you can update the view appropriately.
thus viewmodels talk to each other and views are updated by corresponding view.
 this way you wont be violating any MVVM principle.

Comment: But my UserControl doesn't have a viewmodel. Messenger is used only to talk on viewmodel level (viewmodel to viewmodel). Are you suggesting I should create a viewmodel for my UserControl ?